# How to configure weblogic plugin in apache for the same Location for different clusters?

Tags: apache, weblogic, cluster-computing

I'm wondering if the following setup can work.

I have 2 weblogic clusters with each 2 nodes, all providing the same application:

- cluster-1 with nodes 10.0.0.1:7045 and 10.0.0.2:7045
- cluster-2 with nodes 10.0.0.3:7045 and 10.0.0.4:7045

Can I configure the weblogic plugin in apache as follows :

```
  <Location /service>
     WebLogicCluster 10.0.0.1:7045,10.0.0.2:7045,10.0.0.3:7045,10.0.0.4:7045
     SetHandler weblogic-handler
  </Location>
```

If so, what is the expected behavior ? For example, will there be fail-over between nodes of a different cluster ?

Is there any other way of doing this (I don't want fail-over between nodes of different clusters) ?

Thank you.

[Weblogic 10.0, apache 2.0.64, weblogic module mod_wl_20, SunOS 5.10]

Comment: All the Apache Weblogic plugin does is to forward the requests to the servers listed in WebLogicCluster attribute. It doesn't know that they are in different cluster in the WebLogic domain. In short the answer is no. If you are having four servers from different clusters serving "/service" url then why wouldn't you want failover across clusters?

Comment: Thank you Mani. We don't want fail-over because the clusters/nodes are serving a buggy application that sometimes brings a whole cluster down. By splitting a single cluster into multiple clusters with no fail-over between the clusters we are hoping to achieve better up-time. I know, we should fix the root cause in the first place, but that been proven very hard.

Comment: Have two Apache instances which point to different WebLogic clusters. Use a load balancer to redirect requests to these two Apache servers which inturn load-balances the requests to the WebLogic servers. Its a valid solution only if you have fewer no. of clusters and the number of clusters don't keep changing. Again, like you already said fixing the root cause is a much better option. Also, think in the lines of automatic restart of the cluster if it goes down. There are WebLogic properties if set will restart clusters/servers automatically if failed.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no - the plugin will honour session stickiness for an individual member of the cluster, but on losing a cluster member where a user has session state, it will assume that any other member of that cluster is a valid failover target, and the user will likely lose their state information. That means you're providing *less* availability than if you just had two servers for the same cluster.

It might seem like a trite question, but take a step back and look at the problem you're trying to solve - why don't you want failover between nodes of different clusters? With WebLogic 10 (without checking config) you should be able to use cross-cluster replication to ensure user state information is available in any of the servers.

I'm assuming that the servers aren't all members of the same cluster because they're on separate sites?

Comment: Thank you. I was already afraid of that. Do you have a solution for my problem: I want different clusters, no fail-over between the clusters, but all accessible through 1 and the same url served by apache ?